# web application Java EE and CSV files

Tags: database, jakarta-ee, network-programming, java-ee-5

I am developing a web application (Java EE) to upload CSV files on the server. 
My question is the following: How can I save these CSV files?
my reasoning is as the following:

1-  create a data base

2- **retrieve the data from CSV files(How?)**

3- **Data will be saved in the data base (using JPA and DAO)**

when I searched on the net, I found annotations for CSV files( the JPA of CSV) , and I found also java functions to parse the CSV files and extract data. But but it  is still unclear for me wich solution to opt for or if there are other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Play framework](http://www.playframework.org/).

Comment: It provides the jpa implementation and support for uploading files.I don think parsing csv is a big problem